# Jacobian linearization, does it need to be around a hyperbolic fixed-point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Everything that I read about Jacobian linearization of systems of nonlinear equations is about approximations near hyperbolic fixed-points (cf. [the Hartman-Grobman theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem)).

It seems to me that even nonlinear systems, provided that they have a solution, qualify for Taylor expansions. I don't see why a Jacobian linearization of a surface would not hold when evaluated in the neighborhood of any point. What am I not seeing?

Comment: Because the linearisation fails if the fixed point is non-hyperbolic, i.e. at least one eigenvalue is zero, and therefore the Taylor expansion does NOT have a linear part. As a result, the resulting approximation will be at least a $2$-nd order one, and all the result that you may obtain studying the Jacobian may not be true.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, why does the Taylor expansion not have a linear part if the Jacobian is not full ranked?

Comment: Because if the rank is not full, then the determinant is zero. Therefore at least one eigenvalue has zero real part, i.e. the coefficient of the first order term in the Taylor expansion is nil. As a result, you will have from second order terms onwards.

Comment: @7raiden7 Sorry but why are we talking about the determinant of the Jacobian? The Taylor expansion involves only outer products $\nabla^k\otimes F$, the first of which is the Jacobian itself, not its determinant. Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe reading about the Poincare-Bendixon theorem (http://www.math.hmc.edu/~levy/181_web/Zimmerman_web.pdf) can be helpful. 

Briefly, to have the linear system behave like the non-linear one, Jacobian's eigenvalues must have non-zero real part. For stability, they must have non-positive real part.

Otherwise, you should analyse the equilibrium manifold.

Comment: @7raiden7 Thank you for this link, I will take the time to read this carefully. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that a nonhyperbolic system doesn't *have* a Taylor expansion around the equilibrium. The question is what conclusions one can draw by looking only at the linear terms in that expansion.

For example, think of the linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
.
$$
(Eigenvalues $\pm i$, so not hyperbolic.)
The orbits are periodic (concentric circles around the origin). Now, for an orbit to exactly return where it started is a very delicate thing, so if you perturb the system by adding higher-order terms, you can easily break this property and get a nonlinar system whose flow is qualitatively very different from the flow of its linear part (for example, the orbits might be spirals towards the origin).

The hyperbolicity condition is a "robustness" condition which is necessary in order to be able to guarantee that the nonlinear system really behaves like its linear part (near the equilibrium, of course).

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand your answer. Is it correct to think that hyperbolicity has something to do with some upper bound of the Taylor remainder then (higher order terms)?

Comment: From a purely lexical point of view, that would make sense actually. An "hyperbolic form" would directly constrain the local curvature (second derivative) of the surface. I'm not sure about the relevance of this geometric analogy though.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: Sort of, but perhaps it would be an oversimplification to say that it's *only* about that... (If you read something about stable/unstable/center manifolds maybe it will become clearer. The hyperbolic case is when there is no center manifold.)